# How to have chart column with two colors?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I am working with charts. I have a simple chart with 2 columns, one green and one red:

[image]

I would like to have the green column to turn yellow when its value exceeds 60.

How could I achieve that?

I have made the chart by manually add 2 datapoint (one for each serie) so there is not code that is generating this chart so far.

Comment: What chart control is it?

Comment: Please show the code you are currently using to render the chart!

Comment: This is not easy. Short of using a stacked chart as a workaround with all its problems you will need to ownerdraw the columns. Other charttypes, like point, line or spline are simple to draw but columns are not. Here [is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801190/let-column-charts-overlap-in-chart-control/40804678?s=1|0.5463#40804678) of doing it although not for the purpose of using two colors but of controlling width and overlapping.. Also: We need to see relevant code; here is is quite unclear if you have one or, more likely two series, which can make a big difference!!!

Comment: Thank you for the info TaW. I will leave this for now as this was a bit more complicated than I can handle at the moment.

Comment: Indeed, complicated. The in a way simplest workaround would be to overlay the chartarea with a second one which holds the very same series and datapoints, but with the y-values at the lower lime (e.g. 60) .. If you want to I can show you an example but I would think twice if it is worth it..

Answer (score -1):

You can set custom palette colors on the fly.  Because ms charts don't have a great way to change the color of the column chart, this is a little work around you can use.

```
Color[] colorSet = new Color[]
{
    Color.Yellow,
    Color.Red
};

chart1.PaletteCustomColors = colorSet;
chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.None;
```